# How To Configure PrestoDB internal communication in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, bigdata, presto

I'm testing prestoDB with kubernetes, and I want to configure user and password auth, but it is necessary to have https configured.

Could you help me how to do that on kubernetes?

Im following this page:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security/internal-communication.html

But I didnt understand which domain I should issue a certificate.
Today Im using kubernetes service name resolution like a discovery uri

discovery.uri=http://prestodb-coordinator-service:8080

Comment: Hi Rubens, secure internal communication is different from authentication for user/password. Internal communication means the traffic between nodes are encrypted vs authentication with a user/password can be done a few way like a password file for example. Am I understanding correctly that you want authentication for user login but don't care if the traffic between the nodes is ecrypted?

Comment: probably I will want to configure secure communication between nodes, but now my concern is authentication.

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security/password-file.html

If I understand right, at the first line of this doc said that its necessary https enabled:

"Presto can be configured to enable frontend password authentication over HTTPS for clients, such as the CLI, or the JDBC and ODBC drivers. The username and password are validated against usernames and passwords stored in a file."

Comment: Hmmm okay i'm actually not sure for prestodb how to do this. In Trino (formerly PrestoSQL) you enable https (for clients) https://trino.io/docs/current/security/tls.html and then from that point set up authentication (password file). Also, if you're interested in secure internal communication, that's just setting a property in Trino, vs having to configure every node like prestodb https://trino.io/docs/current/security/internal-communication.html. I would recommend using Trino.

Comment: @BrianOlsen I prefer trino, but I use metabase in my company and metabase doesn't support trino